# How to change the option of select dropdownbox when onclick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nSHaA/4/

```
 Html Code:
<select class="selectMe" name="eye_color"   onChange="setCookie(this.name,this.selectedIndex)">
<option value="default"></option>
<option value="apple">Apple</option>
<option value="banana">Banana</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="lemon">Lemon</option>
</select>

<a href="#" onClick="show()">Click me</a>

<body onLoad="setDefaultValues()">
<div id="default" class="group">
    Default Value
</div>

<div id="apple" class="group">
    Apple Value
</div>

<div id="banana" class="group">
    Banana Value
</div>

<div id="orange" class="group">
    Orange Value
</div>

<div id="lemon" class="group">
    Lemon Value
</div>
</body>
```

Here everything is working fine. But only thing is when I click Click me button it should automatically go to apple div as the selected index should be apple.

Comment: Where is your show() function that you had tried

Comment: No actually the show function is used for some other part, I need this to be happened inside that show() function like function show(){ }

Comment: You have a bunch of unrelated cookie code in your demo, plus your HTML is a mess. Why is there content outside the body tag?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What does "go to apple div" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSHaA/12/)

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('.selectMe').val('apple').change();">Click me</a>
```

Comment: I didn't do that bro. Okay apple div content should also change.